# How can I convert annual standard deviation to a longer period?

Tags: standard-deviation, finance, risk

Quicken provides annual standard deviation of returns for a given portfolio using analysis done by the Newport Group.  I'd like to convert this to a longer term number--say 10, 20, or 30 years.

According to [this article](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/04/101304.asp), you can use the equation:

[image: equation for converting standard deviation]

(Substituting T-years and annually for monthly and daily respectively.)

Is this approximation accurate for such long T?

Comment: This formula assumes there is negligible serial correlation among the returns. This often is not the case and when it is not, the formula can be grossly incorrect, regardless of the length of time.

Comment: To find the SD for 10, 20, or 30 years, take the data from 10, 20, or 30 years and calculate its SD. Anything else would not be the SD.